# How to compare results from two regressions?

Tags: regression, least-squares, model, linear

We have performed two linear regressions (OLS), one with data from 2009 and one with data from 2014. All the variables are the same, both the dependent and the six independent variables. The sample sizes are however different!

We want to be able to compare the results from these two regressions. For instance, we want to test whether some of the independent variables have more significance in one year compared to the other. And also, just a general comparison of the two models: is the dependent variable more explained in one of them?

How can we do this? Are there any statistical tests?

Comment: There are alot of statistical measures available (GINI,deviance, ... ) usingcross validation. But qualitative perspective should be taken into account as well. If you want to use historical data to predict future, even if the model of 2009 is a bit better, I would chose the one of 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you understand for having more significance. Have you considered using all data and adding a factor (levels "2009" and "2014")? You could draw some conclusions based on the interaction coefficients significance.

Comment: The suggestion is the logical one though (i.e. fitting an overall model and seeing whether coefficients differ  by year e.g. by having an interaction with year for all parameters).

Answer (score 1):

To start with, and given that this is a school project, one simple approach would be to look at the $R^2$ of the two regressions. They tell you how much of the variation in the dependent variable is explained by your explanatory variables. If it differs a lot, you may be able to say that your explanatory variables explain more of the variation in one year than the other. Though note that the explanatory power of such a comparison is limited.

As a second exercise, you can use a t-test to see if the coefficients are different from each other. You can either test for equality, or if you have reason to believe that the association between these variables strengthened or weakened, then you can use a one sided t-test. For the t-test, you can use

$t = \frac{\beta^1_i-\beta_i^2 }{\sqrt{\sigma_i^2(\beta^1_i) + \sigma_i^2(\beta^2_i)} } $

where $\beta_i^j$ is the $i$-th coefficient in regression $j \in {1,2}$, and $\sigma_i^2(\beta_i^j)$ is the estimated variance of said coefficient.

The approach suggested by Victor is preferable, though. So, if you manage to execute the regression again, set it up with a dummy for one of the year, interacted with all variables.

Comment: Thanks for answering! What would be the estimated variance of the coefficient? Our regression outputs provides us with the coefficient estimates, their standard errors, t-value and p-value. And also, how would one interpret the result from this test?

Comment: I understand the initial question that you may not immediately know how to compare coefficients from different regressions, but these questions are easy to answer within a few seconds of googling. There are hundreds of tutorials explaining how to do carry out a t-test. Given that this is a school project, I encourage you to do some research on your own.

Comment: Yes, the internet has been very helpful, and the t-test in itself isn't really the issue. We were just wondering about the expression for the t-statistic that you came up with. We are perfectly able to calculate the variance from a sample, but the variance of a coefficient isn't clear to us. Thanks anyway, sorry to bother you.